# Css clip alternative

Tags: css

See my case below in the code snippet. I have used the CSS `clip` property to cut the left rounded part of the button, but I [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip) this property is strongly deprecated. How can I do the same without clip? Putting the input box on top of the button does not mask the shadow of the button. Also `clip-path` is not an option because of poor browser support.

```css
.container {
 position:relative;
 width:250px;
 height:30px;
 background-color:#e0e0e0;
 padding:10px;
}

.myButton {
 position:absolute;
 z-index:1;
 top:10px;
 left:165px; 
 box-shadow:0 2px 2px 0 #c0c0c0;
 border-radius:5px;
 border:1px solid #888; 
 font-weight:600;
 text-decoration:none !important;
 cursor:pointer;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:"Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 line-height:18px;
 clip: rect(0px,100px,200px,5px); 
}

.myButton span {
 display:block;
 line-height:23px;
 height:23px;
 font-size:13px;
 padding:0 8px 0 12px 
}

.myButton {
 color:#fff;
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#79d1ff 0%, #389ee5 100%); 

}

.myButton:hover {
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ec7ebf 0%,#d85da5 35%,#b5006c 70%,#b5006c 100%);
 color:#FFF 
}

.myInput {
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 width:166px;
 height:19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input name="name" class="myInput" type="text" />
  <a href="javascript:;" class="myButton"><span>Submit</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply rely on some overflow with negative margin. Here is an update of your code:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.myButton {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 5px;
  left: 165px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  overflow:hidden; /*Added This code */
  padding:5px 5px 5px 0;
}

.myButton span {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  line-height: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 8px 0 12px;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #79d1ff 0%, #389ee5 100%);
  margin-left:-8px; /* Added this code*/
}

.myButton:hover span {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ec7ebf 0%, #d85da5 35%, #b5006c 70%, #b5006c 100%);
  color: #FFF
}

.myInput {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  width: 166px;
  height: 19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input name="name" class="myInput" type="text">
  <a class="myButton"><span>Submit</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Only the shadow of the button is missing now, but that only needs some tweaking I guess. I think that this is what I need.

Comment: @esims fixed ;) just consider some padding